# flash ,black screen after movie end on full screen mode

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen, flash-cc

i have a flash file in local , it have a flv movie on first frame . in the moviecomplete event it go to another frame . the problem is that when i play it in full screen after end of movie only a black screen remain that i could pass  by pressing esc . how can i remove this?  its my code

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
   stage.scaleMode = "showAll";

load1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadvideoComplete);
load1.fullScreenTakeOver = false;

load1.play();
function loadvideoComplete(event: Event): void //event:Event not event:VideoEvent
{
    //load1.visible=false;
    trace("loadvideoComplete");
    gotoAndPlay("index");
}
```

hiding video didnt worked either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the video completes, change the display state back to normal:

```
function loadvideoComplete(event: Event): void //event:Event not event:VideoEvent
{
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;

    //load1.visible=false;
    trace("loadvideoComplete");
    gotoAndPlay("index");
}
```

Comment: its not the best way but it seems that there is not another good way . i have two suspact 1. some ppl say its a security problem (only a user can exit fullscreen)and some say its cuse of stage.scaleMode = "showAll"; and my stage an movie arent the same size it cuse the black sreen any way, i used this code stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
  gotoAndPlay("index");
  
  stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; tnx alot for ur answer.